# How to join an array of strings into a single string Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4

Prior to Swift 4 I used the code below to join an array of strings into a single string:

```
let array = ["Andrew", "Ben", "John", "Paul", "Peter", "Laura"]
let joined = array.joined(separator: ", ")

 //output:- "Andrew, Ben, John, Paul, Peter, Laura"
```

But now in Swift 4 and Xcode 9 is showing one of the following errors:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'joined()'
>
> Value of type 'TYPE' has no member 'join'

How can I join all elements of an array? Was the syntax changed in Swift 4?

[image]

Comment: it works for me ... ?????

Comment: It is working :)

Comment: update my  question see the pic

Comment: Why you have used `flatMap` ? Could u describe what would you like to achive ?

Comment: I'm using flatMap convert string type array in Integer

Comment: As a rule of thumb, `String(describing:)` is almost never what you want (even if the compiler suggests it as a Fix-it).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's a typical example where *pseudo-code* in the question is misleading and doesn't reproduce the error.

The error occurs because you are using `flatMap`. Since the array is a non-optional single-level array of `Int` just use `map` and don't use the `describing` initializer:

```
func getNumbers(array : [Int]) -> String {
    let stringArray = array.map( String.init )
    return stringArray.joined(separator: ",")
}
```

The ambiguity is that `flatMap` applied to an non-optional sequence has a different meaning:

From the documentation

> ```
> let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>
> let mapped = numbers.map { Array(count: $0, repeatedValue: $0) } 
> // [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
>
> let flatMapped = numbers.flatMap { Array(count: $0, repeatedValue: $0) }
>  // [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
> ```
>
> In fact, `s.flatMap(transform)` is equivalent to `Array(s.map(transform).joined())`.

Comment: Thanks it's working.Please also add the source in the answer if you have.